# how to stop a running thread with button toggle (android app)

Tags: android

I finally got my app working, i just have one issue which i would like to correct.

I have a button which controls a thread that runs a couple function in the background. The functions in the background eventually stop the thread whenever a certain value is reached. What i am having issues doing is pressing that same button again to just stop the thread manually. Currently I can only start the thread and wait for itself to finish. I am able to do other things in the app, so the thread is running on its own, i just want to kill it manually.

```
    public void onMonitorClick(final View view){
    if (isBLEEnabled()) {
        if (!isDeviceConnected()) {
                // do nothing
        } else if (monitorvis == 0) {
            showMonitor();
            DebugLogger.v(TAG, "show monitor");
            //monitorStop = 4;
            Kill.runThread();         // I want a function here that would kill the 
                                     // thread below, or is there something that 
                                     // can be modified in runThread()?
                                     // I did try Thread.Iteruppted() without luck
            shutdownExecutor();

        } else if (monitorvis == 1) {
            hideMonitor();
            DebugLogger.v(TAG, "hide monitor");
            monitorStop = 0;
            runThread(); //The running thread that works great on its own

        }
    } 
    else {
        showBLEDialog();
    }
}



private void runThread() {

    new Thread() {
        int i;
        public void run() {
            while (monitorStop != 3) {  //This is where the thread stops itself 
                try {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            ((ProximityService.ProximityBinder) getService()).getRssi();
                            rssilevel = ((ProximityService.ProximityBinder) getService()).getRssiValue();
                            mRSSI.setText(String.valueOf(rssilevel) + "dB");
                            detectRange(rssilevel);
                        }
                    });
                    Thread.sleep(750);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On first look, you could simply set monitorStop = 3, which would cause the thread to eventually stop after it's timeout completes.

The problem with this, is that I presume if you push the button again or your code modifies monitorStop at some point in the future, then the thead you wanted dead, might stay alive.   ie: monitorStop will need to stay equal to three for at least 750ms to assure the thread will comlete it's loop and die.

The correct way to do this would be to create your thread as a new class with it's own monitorStop parameter.  When you create the thread, you would keep a reference to it and modify the thread's monitorStop parameter.  This way the thread would finish without interruption.  If you wanted to create a new thread, then this would not affect the old thread from finishing appropriately.

Comment: Why don't you use an Handler? It will start your work in a new thread and when you want to stop it, just use removeCallbacks method

Comment: There was a way back in the early days of Java to call stop on a thread, however this has issues and is deprecated.  There's a nice write up on why here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html